# Computing a formula for $\partial^2 f/\partial{v}\partial{w}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be of class $C^2$. Putting $x = u + v - w$, $y = 2u - 3v$, $z = v + 2w$ makes f into a function of u, v, and w. Compute a formula for $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial{v}\partial{w}}$$ in terms of the partial derivatives of f with respect to x, y, and z.

Here is my go at it:
$$
= \frac{\partial}{\partial{v}}( \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{w}}) \\
= \frac{\partial}{\partial{v}} (\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}*\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{w}} +
 \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}} * \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{w}}) \\
= \frac{\partial}{\partial{v}} (-\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}} + 2\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}) \\
= -(\frac{\partial}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}) + 2(\frac{\partial}{\partial{v}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z}}) \\
= -(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}*1) + 2(\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{z^2}}*1) \\
= 2\frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{z^2}} - \frac{\partial^2{f}}{\partial{x^2}}
$$
I have two questions.
1) Is the statement I wrote true? Are all the operations I did value?
2) Did I actually answer the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial w}$ is in terms of $x$, $y$, and $z$, you'll need to be careful with how you rewrite $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial v}$.  Since we know that
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} &= \frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \\ &= \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)f\end{aligned}$$
it follows that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial w}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$

Hence, we similarly have that

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$
and thus
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial v\partial w} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}\right) + \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}\right) + \frac{\partial z}{\partial v}\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}\right)$$